# PHP json decode isnt working on a text/x-json string (WAZE route calculation API)

Tags: php, content-type, json

Trying to get a response with type text/x-json

and json decode it (fails)

this is my code snippet :

```
<?php

//prepare URL (in this example send WAZE web site a route calculation
$url = "http://www.waze.com/RoutingManager/routingRequest?from=x%3A-73.8876574+y%3A40.7664011+bd%3Atrue&to=x%3A-73.7721035+y%3A40.7486434+bd%3Atrue&returnJSON=true&returnGeometries=true&returnInstructions=true&timeout=60000&nPaths=2";

//send GET request to WAZE web site 
$response = file_get_contents($url);

//All this isnt working 
//$response = utf8_encode($response);
//$response = preg_replace("#(/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/)|([\s\t]//.*)|(^//.*)#", '', $response);
//$response = preg_replace('/.+?({.+}).+/','$1',$response);

//go json
$responseJson = json_decode($response);
// this isnt working 2
//$responseJson = json_decode($response,true);

//now $responseJson is null :(

HELP!

?>
```

This is the response header that i get :

```
$http_response_header   Array [6]   
    0   (string:15) HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
    1   (string:25) Content-Type: text/x-json   
    2   (string:35) Date: Sun, 29 Sep 2013 19:36:08 GMT 
    3   (string:19) Server: nginx/1.4.1 
    4   (string:30) X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE7  
    5   (string:17) Connection: Close
```

please help

Thanks

Comment: Use json_decode with second parameter as true, then print_r($responseJson). I guess it will work.

Comment: Malik - thanks for the help but it isnt working (updated the question)

Answer (score 1):

The data returned from the given URL is invalid JSON (it gives some values as `NaN`, which is valid in a JavaScript object literal, but not in JSON). You would need to get the source to fix the errors in it (or to try to patch them yourself after downloading the data).

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine,but not sure if this will work every time.

```
$url = "http://www.waze.com/RoutingManager/routingRequest?from=x%3A-73.8876574+y%3A40.7664011+bd%3Atrue&to=x%3A-73.7721035+y%3A40.7486434+bd%3Atrue&returnJSON=true&returnGeometries=true&returnInstructions=true&timeout=60000&nPaths=2";

//send GET request to WAZE web site
$response = file_get_contents($url);


$response = str_replace("NaN",'"NaN"',$response);

$responseJson = json_decode($response,true);
```